# chessboard 7x 7

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, education

A 7 × 7 chessboard that is painted black and white, with the corners painted black;and we have the operator "inverse", which can be applied to a single row or single column in a table that it change the color of the cell from white to black or from black to white ( for example the first cell at row 2 in the chessboard colerd by white and the second is black.... if i will use "inverse" to this row it will change the first cell to black and the second to white ...)
The goal is to make the whole board colered black. What is the minimum number of steps required to achieve the goal?

there is two soultion for this question, i need the two soultions!!

Comment: i have one answer now: at the begining i will "inverse" row 2 alone then row 4 then row 6 , now i have colmun 2, 4, and 6 is colered by white i will " inverse then but each one separately, but i need another solution:(

Comment: "which can be applied to a single row or single column ... by white and the second is black.... if i will use "inverse" to this row it will change the first cell to black and the second to white ...)"  These are three inconsistent statements.  The first says something undefined happens to an entire row or column.  The second says it only applies to a single cell.  The third says it applies only to the first two cells of a row or column.  Why not just say "it reverses the colors of all cells in a row or column"?

Comment: i can say it reverses the colors of all cells in a row or in a colmun, im not that good in english

Comment: Well, it's easy to see you can do it in 6 turns by inverting rows 2,4 and 6.  That leaves the board completely striped.  Then invert colums 2,4,6 to make them all black.  The question is is there any better.

Comment: yes, i write this answer at the first comment, but i need another way to solve it... thank you, do u have another way??

Comment: can you help me and write the question in a good way?? @fleablood

Comment: I guess the other way is to start by columns 2,4,6 so then the stripped pattern is rotated compared to your solution. Does that count for another solution ? You can also alternate rows and columns to have a mixed pattern, in the end after 6 moves it is still all black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If we consider the initial board, we just have to reverse $3$ rows and $3$ columns as indicated by the external stones on the picture above.

*Note: $6$ moves is the minimal number since if we consider the stones on the top edge and right edge for instance, there are $6$ of them and they need to be reversed anyway. This cannot be done in less than $6$ operations.*

The order has no importance, you can start by the rows $2,4,6$ and then all the columns, but you can also select any row or column that has not been already reversed.

[image]

For instance here is the status after $1$ column was reversed.

[image]

And after $2$ rows and $1$ column were reversed.

If you continue the process, with the remaining $3$ marked available moves, you end up with an all black board, no matter the order of the moves.

---

The reason it works is the following when you consider the possible moves (stones on the outside) you will notice that white stones can be reversed by only $1$ possible move while black stones can be reversed with $0$ or $2$ of them.

The order is not important, the parity is. Assuming we do not repeat a previously made reversal, then white stones will be flipped once (and become black) and black stones will be flipped zero or twice (and remain black).

In the end the whole board turns black.